# Cofiltered diagram of path connected spaces with empty homotopy limit?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Is it possible to have a filtered category $J$, a functor $F: J^\mathrm{op} \to \mathrm{Spaces}$ such that $F(i)$ is path connected for all $i$ and such that $\mathrm{holim} F = \emptyset$?

If $J$ is countable the answer is no, since the diagram may then be replaced by one indexed by $J = (\mathbb{N},\leq)$ and a point in the homotopy limit may be constructed by picking points $x_n \in F(n)$ and paths in $F(n)$ from $x_n$ to $F(n+1 > n)(x_{n+1})$.

Comment: Maybe the following works.  Start with a cofiltered diagram $i \mapsto A_i$ of abelian groups with $\lim^2 A_i \neq 0$, which apparently exists.  Apply bar construction twice and then fibrant replacement to get a cofiltered diagram of spaces $i \mapsto X_i \simeq K(A_i,2)$ with $\pi_0 \lim X_i = lim^2 A_i \neq \{0\}$.  Pick $x, y \in \lim X_i$ in different path components, with projections $x_i, y_i \in X_i$, and let $Y_i = \Omega_{x,y} X_i \simeq K(A_i,1)$ be the space of paths $I \to X_i$ from $x_i$ to $y_i$.  Then (?) the cofiltered diagram $i \mapsto Y_i$ has empty homotopy limit.